# How do you force NPM to reinstall a package at the same version with new content, essentially ignoring hash changes & updating the package-lock.json?

Tags: npm

Our scenario is that we're *intentionally* republishing prerelease versions of packages with the same version but different content to a private npm registry as we go about our daily development.  For example, we'll initially publish, say, version `0.1.0-dev.0` of a package with some content in a CI pipeline.  Then, later, we'll unpublish that version, then republish `0.1.0-dev.0` with *new* content, which obviously causes downstream `EINTEGRITY` errors on subsequent `npm install` invocations because the package hash has changed.

We fully understand that this is undesirable for publicly available packages, prerelease or not, but this process is for before we publicly release.  Once released, we would not obviously not do this.

How can we instruct `npm install` to *ignore* integrity violations for specific packages or scopes, install the packages at their specified versions anyway, and *update* the `integrity` hashes in the `package-lock.json` for those packages?

Assume our company is called "Acme" with scope `@acme`.  Our only current workaround is an npm script that is called `refresh-acme` that is something like `rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules/@acme && npm install`, which seems kludgy.  One thought I had was to append semver build metadata like a short git SHA or timestamp, for example, `0.1.0-dev.0+56a8f3` or `0.1.0-dev.0+20230731102932Z`, but I've heard of problems with NPM ignoring or dropping semver build metadata, plus it's just inconvenient for developers to have to go look up the right SHA or timestamp.